# My <section> is stuck with my <nav>, I can't get margin to separate them

Tags: html, css

I'm making a product landing page, and I need a fixed nav bar, and below it a form. For some reason these two keep getting stuck together, although I gave `position="fixed"` on the nav bar CSS.

```css
* {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

section {
  margin: 50px 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header id="header">

    <img id="header-img" src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png" width="300px"></div>

    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#Features">Features</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#How_It_Works">How It Works</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#Pricing">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section>
    <h2>Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces</h2>
    <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="GET STARTED">
    </form>
  </section>

</body>
```

This somehow makes them stuck together. I keep trying by adding a margin on the `<section>` CSS, but why does it apply to the navbar too?

I keep trying by adding a margin on the `<section>` CSS, but why does it apply to the navbar too?

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean "stuck together"? The `header` is fixed to the browser window. That means it's taken out of document flow. Also,  you have a `<\div>` after your image, without an opening tag.

Answer (score 2):

- you need to add position coordinates too, if not by default it will just float where it was supposed to be. so adding `top:0` in the header tag CSS will fix the issue, you can in the snippet below.
- Also pointing another mistake in HTML you closed `<img>` tag with `</div>`

```css
*{
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  display: flex;
  top:0;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

section{

  margin: 50px 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <header id="header">
     
      <img id="header-img"src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png" width="300px"/>

      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#Features">Features</a></li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#How_It_Works">How It Works</a></li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#Pricing">Pricing</a></li>
          </ul>
          </nav>
          </header>

      <section>
        <h2>Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces</h2>
        <form id="form"  action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
          <input type="submit" id="submit" value="GET STARTED">
        </form>
      </section>

        </body>
```